# Export Awesomebar history in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, sqlite, history, xul

Is there any way to export the history information from the Firefox address bar into a file?

I have been searching for docs online, but cannot find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: I switched the browsers tag to sqlite as you are specifically asking for help with exporting data from Firefox and not browsers in general.

Answer (score 1):

This post shows how to [clear the SQLite database](http://lifehacker.com/5344418/make-firefox-faster-by-vacuuming-your-database) of contents. You should be able to execute some show tables, select * to get the content.

Answer (score 1):

The bookmark data is going to be located in %appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles[randomcharacters].default\places.sqlite (or whatever your profile is instead of default). The moz_places table should be what you're interested in. [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index) works for taking a peek at it, though another program might have more robust options for extracting and exporting the data in the way you want. Though if you can't find one, you could just use a programming interface like [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) to extract the data.